# Making all pages a consistent height cross-desktop-browsers

Tags: javascript, css, ajax

I have a client requesting that all pages on their WordPress website be the height of the longest page on the site, regardless of actual content height for each specific page. The plan is to manually edit that height every time the longest page changes height. This leads to large blank spaces at the bottom of short pages, lots of unnecessary style changes, and is against my recommendations to anyone with eyes..

Currently I have a simple `height: 1100px;` set on the content area which works alright. The issue I'm encountering is making it display correctly on all modern browsers at all font sizes - for example: 1100px works fine in Chrome at 100% zoom, but the content extends the given area at 125% zoom. Extend that to each browser, each font size..yep.

I've tried doing a `min-height` and just have it extend slightly more on long pages, but when you flip from one page to the next you can still see that it's a different height. I also had the height set larger than the largest page always, but then it doesn't wrap tight to the longest page so there's excess excess space..

Mobile design is not a priority at the moment - just desktop browsers.

I'm guessing I need some sort of JavaScript/AJAX hackery to load each page on each page, compare the rendered height and set the height accordingly, but I'm hoping someone knows of an easier way. Any ideas?

Comment: Setting the height manually and having it consistent regardless of whether or not the user zooms is not possible.  Zoom is a browser feature that "blows up" the entire page regardless of CSS, and you can't exactly disable it for every browser.  Your client is requesting something that will essentially total their site, and you should tell them that.  This isn't print publishing.

Comment: @J.T.Blum thanks for the note. I've let them know and we're now just using a `min-height` to make the pages never super short yet still able to be longer.